# JavaScript: Resizing laptop's browser window ("mobile"--"desktop"--"mobile") doesn't reboot menu state

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, resize

I use latest Google Chrome and I have the following frontend code for a responsive navigation menu which I use in my WordPress website.

Clicking the `.burger` element makes adjacent `.menu` element to appear or disappear, in dropdown or dropup respectively.

### My problem

1. We open a browser window `<=959px` and we open the mobile menu.
2. We resize the window to `>=960px` and then we resize back to `<=959px`.
3. We have to click the `burger` twice to close the menu, to then re-open it.

### My question

Why do we need to click the burger twice in the given circumstances?

### Code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    let clicks = 0;
    let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-primary');
    let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    let isMenuVisible = false;

    burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible;
      menu.style.display = isMenuVisible ? 'block' : 'none';
    });

    let mobileBehavior = ()=>{
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    };

    if (window.innerWidth <= 959) {
      mobileBehavior();
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
      if (window.innerWidth <= 959) {
        clicks = 1;
      } else if (window.innerWidth >= 960) {
        menu.style.display = 'block';
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.burger {
    display: block;
    text-align: center; color: var(--w);
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    font-weight: bold
}

#menu-primary { display: none }

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .burger { display: none }
    #menu-primary { display: block }
}
```

```html
<div class="burger">BARS</div>

<ul id="menu-primary">
  <li>Homepage</li>
  <li>Contact_us</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: One could test this live on my website: integrative-massage.co.il

Comment: To summarize the comments in the various answers regarding OP's issue with having to click twice to open or close the hamburger menu after resizing the browser: the issue is not present in the code snippet included with the question but apparently occurs on OP's website (and remains unresolved by any of the answers posted / edited prior to the time of this comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, you are trying to accomplish the following:

1. Create a hamburger style drop down menu or navigation drawer that opens and closes on a `click` event.
2. Only show the hamburger and related menu on mobile screens.
3. If a mobile-sized screen is resized to a desktop size while the hamburger menu is open: a) the hamburger and related menu are both hidden, and b) the menu display is "reset" so that if the screen is resized back to a mobile size the hamburger is displayed but the related menu is not.

The other answers have addressed one or more of the above items but not all of them. Following is an approach to putting them all together; however, I would recommend against implementing "3b" above unless you have an unusual use case for your app or site (I don't think most casual users are resizing their screens from mobile to desktop and then back to mobile sizes very often, but maybe I am wrong, and I don't know that it would matter much if the drop down menu was still visible if someone did go through this sort of resizing experiment).

I have added some additional `html` and `css` for styling purposes because it was hard to visually see the effects of toggling the menu display and resizing the screen with a spartan setup (also handled the display of the menu with the `visibility` attribute and `position: absolute` so that it doesn't impact the positioning of other elements when the display is toggled.

The functional code for your specific purpose are the javascript and the css styles for the `.burger`, `.burger-menu`, `.hidden`, and `.desktop` classes (including the related media query).

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const burgerMenu = document.querySelector('.burger-menu');
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  burgerMenu.classList.toggle('hidden');
});

// not recommended (but this "resets" the menu display on resize)
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  if (window.matchMedia('(min-width:960px)').matches) {
    burgerMenu.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

nav ul:first-child {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.burger {
  display: inline-block;
}

.burger div {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 4px 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 3px;
}

.burger-menu {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .burger {
    display: none;
  }
  .burger-menu {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .desktop {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="burger">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </li>
    <ul class="burger-menu hidden">
      <li>Home (mobile)</li>
      <li>Contact (mobile)</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="desktop">Home (desktop)</li>
    <li class="desktop">Contact (desktop)</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel augue ipsum. Donec suscipit nisi magna, ac condimentum est blandit a.
</div>
```

Comment: I think you understand me correctly but the main problem I see is that when starting in desktop then resizing to mobile (opening the menu and keepting it open) then to desktop, then to mobile again, WE WOULD HAVE TO DOUBLE CLICK the burger to show the menu. I wonder why that happened.

Comment: Hmm... I am not able to replicate that behavior in Chrome. To be sure I am following you: 1) open the page at a desktop size (burger hidden), 2) resize the page to a mobile size (burger displayed), 3) click burger to display burger menu, 4) resize the page to a desktop size (burger and burger menu hidden), and finally 5) resize the page to a mobile size. At this point you are having to double-click the burger to get the menu to open again (I only have to click once in Chrome)? What browser are you using?

Comment: Exactly, you understood me correctly. I also use (latest) Chrome and indeed I need to click the burger twice in stage 5...

Comment: It happens to me in (latest) Firefox as well, sadly. I'm from Windows 10. You could test this directly in my site (please see link above in question comments).

Comment: Do you have to double click when running the code snippet in this answer? Or does it only happen on your site (could be some conflicting code that is not included in your question)?

Comment: benvc, it happens only in my site and I'm having trouble finding how to deal with this; It comes either from WordPress, the theme, or a plugin.

Comment: @JohnDoea those sorts of bugs can be tricky to hunt down. If you just don't know where to start, then you might copy just the navbar related html and css from your site into a clean wordpress template and then add, one by one, your other css, js, and other dependencies to try and pinpoint which one is the culprit. If you are able to isolate the source of the issue but still unable to fix it, you can always post a question that includes the offending code so we can help you work around it.

Comment: benvc, there might be some radical approach I could take here? I seems that hte `.menu` element itself gets the CSS directive before double clicking. No `addEventListener()` will help here I think. Maybe a more general, violent, radical approach can be taken? but what would that be?... :\\\

Comment: @JohnDoea can you recreate the issue in a codepen (or something similar) with just the menu html and whatever css, scripts, libraries, etc you are using? That way we can see both behavior and code (on your site, we only see part of the story).

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to do that and doesn't have any spare time to research that.

Answer (score 2):

you are using too much javascript, you could simplify it by toggling a class on the element when you click the bar and put the 'logic' in css.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-primary');
    let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');

    burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      menu.classList.toggle('collapse');
    });
});
```

```css
.burger {
    display: block;
    text-align: center; color: var(--w);
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu-primary.collapse{
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .burger { display: none }
  #menu-primary.collapse{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="burger">BARS</div>

<ul id="menu-primary">
  <li>Homepage</li>
  <li>Contact_us</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't hide the menu when the screen is sized to < 959px.

Comment: you can just default the `#menu-primary` to have `.collapse` ? like this one here https://codepen.io/poldiwa/pen/dqNNXG

Comment: That won't work because you need to actively check for the window width. A CSS class can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not closing the menu when the browser width is initially resized to `<= 959`. To do this efficiently, you just need a boolean variable to control the menu closing so it only happens one time at the breakpoint and then resets when the browser width is resized to `>= 960`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const menu = document.querySelector('#menu-primary');
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const breakpoint = 959;
  let switched = false;

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.style.display = menu.style.display !== 'block' ? 'block' : 'none';
  });

  if (window.innerWidth <= breakpoint) {
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    switched = true;
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= breakpoint) {
      if (!switched) {
        switched = true;
        menu.style.display = 'none';
      }
    } else {
      if (switched) {
        switched = false;
        menu.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ineed now the menu appear closed when re-resizing to `<=768px` but there is still a problem: After re-resizing I should click the "menu" button twice to open it --- you could see it live on [my site](http://integrative-massage.co.il).

Comment: @JohnDoea I have corrected the issue. It should only require one click to open the menu now.

Comment: Hmm, there seem to be another problem now where resizing back to larger screens (`>=769px`) makes the entire menu disappear.

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing to get that to happen? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I did the exact same course I did earlier (the same course in my question under "My problem" chapter).

Comment: You might want to see feedback on this here, the problem might be because I used `let` instead `const`, can't test right now: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/202303/javascript-responsive-menu-dropdown-dropup

Comment: That would not cause any issues. Using `const` is only a way to catch yourself trying to change something that shouldn't be changed. In this case that doesn't apply. I checked my code with Chrome v68.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. The `isMenuVisible` variable was making the logic a little confusing since the check can be done directly with the value of `menu.style.display`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target a certain breakpoint and run some code when resize hits it, you can use `window.matchMedia` and it works with breakpoint range as well.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {

    // single breakpoint
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width:768px)").matches) {
        // your logic here        
    }

    // you can target breakpoint range as well
    // window.matchMedia("(min-width:375px) and (max-width:768px)").matches

});
```

On a side note, you may need to [throttle resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#Examples) if you're performing expensive dom operations.