# What's the difference between x=false AND x=!x TO x=false AND x=true?

Tags: javascript, logic, operators

This question is a follow up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990611/javascript-resizing-laptops-browser-window-mobile-desktop-mobile-doe/52119743#52119743).

What is the difference between:

```
let isMenuVisible = false;

burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible;
  menu.style.display = isMenuVisible ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

to

```
let isMenuVisible = false;

burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  isMenuVisible = true;
  menu.style.display = isMenuVisible ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

I fail to understand why the latter code failed; they seem to me equivalent (as the negation of `false` is `true`, isn't it?).

Comment: `isMenuVisible = true;` will always set the value to true. `isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible;` will change the value, if false, then now is true, if true, then now is false;

Comment: Is that all of your code? It's possible the value gets changed someone else before the event listener is added.

Comment: What do you mean by failed

Comment: It will be the same the first time the listener is invoked. On the second call, `isMenuVisible` will be set to `false` in the first snippet - in the second one it will stay `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all inside your **burger.addEventListener** the `isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible;` and `isMenuVisible = true` is not the same thing.

`isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible;` means what ever the value of `isMenuVisible` is now do it alternative e.g if it is `true` then make it `false`, if it is `false` then make it `true`

and

`isMenuVisible=true` means set it `true`
`isMenuVisible=false` means set it `false`

Answer (score 0):

.In first case `isMenuVisible` is false so `!isMenuVisible` will be true;

`isMenuVisible =!isMenuVisible` will set the value of `isMenuVisible` will change on every `click` event

In second case instead of assigning the value through a variable `true` is directly assigned to `isMenuVisible` and the value will never `toggle`

Answer (score 0):

```
isMenuVisible = !isMenuVisible:
```

This is like flipping card. If we set `isMenuVisible = false` initially. After executing the above line once, `isMenuVisible` will be `!isMenuVisible/true`. After another execution, `isMenuVisible` will be `!isMenuVisible/false`.
`isMenuVisible` is getting alter in each execution.

```
isMenuVisible = true:
```

This is just assigning `true` to `isMenuVisible` all the time.